# How to get list of members subscribed to a list - Mailman

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, mailman

I have an Ubuntu server with Postfix and the Mailman list manager. 
My server stopped working, so I need to find a way to list the emails registered on the list of the Mailman.

Note: I was able to mount the data partition, so I have all the files.

Comment: Your title and content are different. Do you need the list of members subscribed to the email list *or* their emails *or* the list of mailing lists manages by Mailman?

Comment: I need the list of members subscribed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything about your list you can find in file `/var/lib/mailman/lists/name_of_list/config.pck`. In this file is whole configuration of list, including subscriber's addresses.

If you need move configuration of mailman to another machine, simply copy directory, subdirectories and files in /var/lib/mailman to the new machine, set the same permission, owner and group for directories and files and everything will work fine again.

Comment: I can not install Mailman for now. How can I open this file to get the emails?

Comment: I've got it. Command: strings config.pck. Thanks Jan Marek!

Comment: @NilsonUehara `strings` is inadequate. I suspected it, then I tried it.